# How can I set a foreign key as primary key with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to set a foreign key as primary key using Entity Framework and fluent api.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Z>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.X)
            .WithRequireDependent(m => m.Y)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

My class:

```
public class Z
{
        [Key,ForeignKey("X")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public RentCar X { get; set; }
        public DateTime AIA_KM { get; set; }
        public DateTime AIA_FEC { get; set; }
}
```

I checked this StackoverFlow question [Entity Framework Foreign Key as Primary Key Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623342/entity-framework-foreign-key-as-primary-key-code-first) before but doesn't work for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the PK of `RentCar` in your `Z` entity and add the following config:

```
public class Z
{
        public int RentCarId { get; set; }//Add this

        public RentCar X { get; set; }
        public DateTime AIA_KM { get; set; }
        public DateTime AIA_FEC { get; set; }
}
```

And add this configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Z>().HasKey(t => t.RentCarId );// Add this
modelBuilder.Entity<Z>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.X)
            .WithRequireDependent(m => m.Y)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

From this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s07.html):

> Selecting `WithRequiredPrincipal` will make the entity that you are
>   configuring the principal, meaning it contains the primary key of the
>   relationship. Selecting `WithRequiredDependent` will make the entity
>   that you are configuring the dependent, meaning it will have the
>   foreign key of the relationship.

So by convention the PK of you dependent entity (`Z`) is going to be the FK of the one to one relationship

Comment: I tried this before and I get the new key field, but I don't get the RentCar X column. Thank you so much. Without the RentCar X column we don't loose the relationship?

Comment: `X` is a navigation property, is like the representation of one of the ends of the relationship, it;s not going to be represented as column in your table

Comment: Hi @DavidJ.E. If you think my answer help you to solve your question, please, consider mark it as answered doing click on the check mark

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work, it says I didn't set the key properly, thank you for your time.

Comment: Does not work. Complains that table doesn't have a key.  For some reason, using the fluent HasKey call doesn't work, but setting the Key attribute does.

Comment: weird, I can't find a logic explanation for you, it should work, `HasKey` is the fluent method to specify a Key